# How do you use the serviceNameFilter when calling QueryClient.GetServiceListAsync

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I'm using Azure Service Fabric with stateless services. I have a list of services deployed under an application, and there's a naming convention used with those service names. I'd like to get a list of services that match a filter expression.

Here is a link to a screenshot of my service fabric explorer. I don't have the reputation points to post an image.

[Service Fabric Explorer screenshot](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2l7aBnfigNxUEpMcHY2YWRCQ0U)

In this example, the name of my application is SFApp1, and the name of my service is HelloWorldStateless. I'd like to query the service fabric cluster to locate all services with the name "HelloWorldSt*" (under the SFApp1 application of course).

I know I can query to find all services with the application name "fabric:/SFApp1", and it'll return all services under that application. This overload of GetServiceListAsync takes just an application URI.

```
FabricClient client = new FabricClient();
ServiceList serviceList = client.QueryManager.GetServiceListAsync(new Uri("fabric:/SFApp1")).Result;
```

I also know I can query to find a specific service. This overload takes an application URI AND a service URI and will return a single-item list.

```
FabricClient client = new FabricClient();
ServiceList serviceList = client.QueryManager.GetServiceListAsync(new Uri("fabric:/SFApp1"), new Uri("fabric:/SFApp1/HelloWorldStateless")).Result;
```

What I'm trying to find out is if there's any way to do something like a wildcard search.

```
FabricClient client = new FabricClient();
ServiceList serviceList = client.QueryManager.GetServiceListAsync(new Uri("fabric:/SFApp1"), new Uri("fabric:/SFApp1/HelloWorldSt*")).Result;
```

The name of the parameter where the service name is specified is serviceNameFilter, and the method returns a list. I'm wondering why they would return a list for this overload if the result was always going to be a single-item list. Also, the parameter name "serviceNameFilter" suggests (to me at least) that there's the ability to supply some kind of expression to narrow down your list.

Here's what I've tried already. I've tried the code above, where I chop off a few characters and put an asterisk. I've tried without the asterisk to see if it was a substring match. I've tried SQL-style, with a percent symbol. I've tried a question mark. All of those attempts returned an empty list.

My current workaround is just to ask for all services under that application, and I'll filter them on the client code end with a linq expression. That'll work, but I worry about performance if my list of services gets really big.

Would be nice if I could inspect the source code to answer this myself.

Is there a way to do what I'm trying to do, or am I just misinterpreting what "serviceNameFilter" means, and it just means you have to put the entire service URI that you're looking for?

Thanks for any help you can provide!

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately that API parameter is terribly named. It's not really a filter at all, it's just the name of the service (since there's no other query that just returns one service, this is how you "filter" from all the services in an application down to just one in particular).

The nearest thing to what you're looking for is EnumerateSubnames. It's not a wildcard search, but you can get all the names that exist "underneath" a given name (for example, all of the service names that exist within an application, or all names with some specific prefix). Depending on the structure of how you create your service names this could work for you.

```
// System.Fabric.FabricClient.PropertyManagementClient
public Task<NameEnumerationResult> EnumerateSubNamesAsync(Uri name, NameEnumerationResult previousResult, bool recursive)
```

For example: Presume the following names exist in the cluster:

1. fabric:/SomeApplication/Zone1/Service1
2. fabric:/SomeApplication/Zone1/Service2
3. fabric:/SomeApplication/Zone2/Service1

Note that in this case the application would have been created with the name "fabric:/SomeApplication" and then the services with the detailed names above incorporating the "Zone" segment.

If you now EnumerateSubnames("fabric:/SomeApplication/Zone1", null, true) you'd get back a result that gave you the full names that matched (1 & 2 above).